# PL/SQL for loop is evaluated before checking the if condition?

Tags: plsql

Here is simple script to check if table FOO exists, which works fine!

```
declare
n number;

begin

select count(*) into n from user_tables where table_name = 'FOO';

if n>0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO exists.');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO not exists.');
end if;

end;
```

The run output is "FOO not exists.", which is what I expected.  Now I want to add some process logic in the block if the table exists.

```
declare
n number;

begin

select count(*) into n from user_tables where table_name = 'FOO';

if n>0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO exists.');
    FOR r in (select name from FOO) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.name);
    end loop;
else
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO not exists.');
end if;

end;
```

Now it gives error:

```
    FOR r in (select name from FOO) loop
                               *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 43:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But why? FOO doesn't exist.  And the if block should NOT execute just like my first script above.

Or is the for loop has to evaluate before the execution and therefore the error?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the script, the object references need to be valid unless you're referencing the objects in quoted strings, such as in dynamic SQL.

For example you could change your script to this:

```
declare
n number;
v_sql_count varchar2(200);
v_sql_names varchar2(200);
TYPE namesTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
v_names namesTable;

begin

v_sql_count := 'select count(*) from user_tables where table_name = ''FOO''';
v_sql_names := 'select name from FOO';

execute immediate v_sql_count into n;

if n>0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO exists.');
    execute immediate v_sql_names bulk collect into v_names;
    FOR r in v_names.first .. v_names.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_names(r));
    end loop;
else
    dbms_output.put_line('FOO not exists.');
end if;

exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('SQLERR: ' || SQLERRM);
end;
```

The two queries (one for the count and one to get the name column) are written as strings and then executed.  Because the invalid names are quoted, they won't be seen as invalid object references and the script will run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `REF CURSOR` to open a cursor based on a dynamic query:

```
DECLARE

    n number;

    TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
    c_foo_query cursor_type;
    v_result varchar2(4000);

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO n
      FROM user_tables
      WHERE table_name = 'FOO';

    IF ( n>0 )
    THEN

        dbms_output.put_line('FOO exists.');

        OPEN c_foo_query FOR 'SELECT name FROM foo';
        LOOP
            FETCH c_foo_query INTO v_result;
            EXIT WHEN c_foo_query%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_result);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_foo_query;

    ELSE

        dbms_output.put_line('FOO not exists.');

    END IF;

 END;
 /
```